# What exactly does pygame.display.set_mode() do?

Tags: python, pygame

I've recently started to play around with the pygame python library and I just wanted to see if I was understanding something correctly:

The following is some code that sets up the window.  In the line that says:

```
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
```

, does `display` refer to a module inside of pygame and is `set_mode` the name of a class in that module?  Is this correct?

```
from pygame.locals import *

# set up pygame
pygame.init()

# set up the window
WINDOWWIDTH = 400
WINDOWHEIGHT = 400
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`display` is a module, and `set_mode` is a *function* inside that module. It actually creates an instance of the `pygame.Surface` class, and returns that. See [the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode).

In Python, the standard is that classes have capitalised names, and modules and functions are all lower case. Not everything follows that, but a lot of things do, and it looks like pygame is one of them.

Comment: ah, I see.  So is it correct to say that set_mode is the "constructor function" i.e. the function within the class that creates the object and initializes the values?

Comment: @sq1020: A 'constructor' normally means a method of a class that's called when you create an instance. So if you say `a = MyClass()` in Python, it makes a new instance of MyClass, and calls its `__init__` method to set it up. An external function that returns new instances of its class might be called a 'factory function'.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that [`display`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html) is a module inside of pygame, but [`set_mode`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) is not a class, it is a method that initializes a [`Surface`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), see the links for more information.