# I bumped in a little problem: argument 1 must be 2-item sequence, not float

Tags: python

I've started coding in Python not long ago and I bumped in a little problem.

Here is the Code:

```
   pygame.init()
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.w/ self.h))
    pygame.display.set_caption('CheetaToise')
```

here's the code I used.

If ever you need more info just ask.

Hope you can help

Comment: Isn't the `/` supposed to be a comma `,` between `self.w` and `self.h`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104207/what-exactly-does-pygame-display-set-mode-do